# How to check some button value with same id javascript

Tags: javascript, html

well guys , i'm new in here ...
how can i check the values on different button with the same id?

sample code:

```
<button onclick="checkValue();" id="price" value="1">
<button onclick="checkValue();" id="price" value="2">
<button onclick="checkValue();" id="price" value="3">
<script>
function checkValue()
    {
        var but = document.getElementById("price").value;
        console.log(but);
    }
</script>
```

well .. how can i obtain 1 or 2 or 3 when it was clicked?

Comment: `id` should be unique and use `class` for group of element

Comment: you can't have `same id`. Use `class` instead.

Comment: @PranavCBalan hmm , you mean i should pass my class attribute to my function and then i got the values?

Comment: @Wilx : check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `id` should be unique so always use `class` for the group of elements. For getting the value pass the `this` context as the argument.

```html
<button onclick="checkValue(this);" value="1">1</button>
<button onclick="checkValue(this);" value="2">2</button>
<button onclick="checkValue(this);" value="3">3</button>
<script>
  function checkValue(ele) {
    console.log(ele.value);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: @Wilx Although this answer does show you how to get the values for each of those buttons, this answer does not show you how to use  `class` rather then `id's` to target group elements. I thought I would just point that out for future reference. `this` will target the element use to trigger that event and obviously `.value` will target the value of the element use to trigger that event which in return you get the `value` of the button clicked. I don't see much point posting an answer so here's an example of using a class. https://jsfiddle.net/dLLavug0/

Comment: @NewToJs : i wanna ask what's the different about event onclick and click? i don't really get it , can you explain it for me :D

Comment: @Wilx when you use attributes it's `onclick` `oninput` `onmouseover` where as if you use javascript events those are `click` `input` `mouseover` all resulting in the same thing.

Comment: @PranavCBalan I agree, a class isn't required for something this simple but since every answer posted to this question is recommending to use a `class` rather than `id` I thought it would make sense to show an example rather than recommending it but showing a different solution.

Comment: @NewToJS :  I don't think that `class` is what he is looking for... he just want to get the `value`

Comment: @PranavCBalan Obviously the OP doesn't know how to use a `class` hence duplicating `id's`. If someone is to explain that `id` should be unique so a `class` should be used. I thought it would be relevant to show how. Sometimes the OP's source is just an example of that what person is looking for, maybe a less complicated version. It's not like I'm trying to get or take credit for your post, I'm just trying to expand on helping Wilx but you seem rather uptight about it. Next time I will just post a detailed answer and avoid having to explain myself.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have multiple elements with the same `id`. If you want to *group* them you can use `class`.

To get the value of the selected button you can send `this` inside the function

```js
function checkValue(elem) {
  console.log(elem.value);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="checkValue(this)" class="price" value="1">1</button>
<button onclick="checkValue(this)" class="price" value="2">2</button>
<button onclick="checkValue(this)" class="price" value="3">3</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<button onclick="checkValue(this);" class="price" id="price1" value="1">Button1
<button onclick="checkValue(this);" class="price" id="price2" value="2">Button2
<button onclick="checkValue(this);" class="price" id="price3" value="3">Button3
<script>
function checkValue(d)
    {
        var but = d.value;
        console.log(but);
    }
</script>
```